# Using axios to make Azure Zip Deploy

Tags: node.js, azure, post, axios

Been struggling with this one, so I need to make a post request to Azure Zip Deploy to get my app there, went from errors such as credentials wrong (fixed) to now where it states

```
axios({
  headers: { "Content-Type": "'application/json'" },
  method: "post",
  url: 'https://test.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy',
  auth: {
    username: '',
    password: ''
  },
  body: {
    file: filePath
  }
});
```

Errors I get
Message: 'An error has occurred.',
ExceptionMessage: 'An attempt was made to move the file pointer before the beginning of the file.\r\n'

Central Directory corrupt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');

siteName = '<your web app name>'
user = '<depolyment user name>'
pwd = '<password>'
ZipPath = '<depolyment zip path>'

stream = fs.createReadStream(ZipPath)

axios({
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-zip-compressed" },
    method: "post",
    url: 'https://'+siteName+'.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy',
    auth: {
      username: user,
      password: pwd
    },
    data: stream
  })
```

I use a static HTML website deployment .zip file to test:

[image]

Log:
[image]

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much , i do think this will work however is possible for you to tell me how would i deploy as a branch when doing this as well ?

Comment: @DipRawal, I am sorry, I am not quite sure about it. Could you pls post an other question for it with detailed content? Once I see it , I'll do some research for you : )
And if my post is helpful, could you pls click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in to accept it as an answer, so that it will help others and close this question : )

Comment: Regardless you've been amazing thanks so much for this tricky question